# Histogram: Compare PDF to Data

Tags: plotting, histograms, charts

## Goal

I would like to make a plot which satisfies the following:

- Formost it should contain the Histogram of the data, with an overlay of the PDF
- Two y-axes, the left being the count for the elements in the bin of the Histogram, the right being the Probability density for the PDF
- Should show the "fit" of the PDF to the histogram of the data (by being at the same scale)

## Code

```
data = RandomVariate[GumbelDistribution[], 1000];
```

While `Histogram` has an option to render the discretized PDF of the data, I rather see the smooth fitted version and the original.

Clearly this will use some combination of `Show` as to show the overlay for the discretized PDF and the smooth PDF one can type:

```
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, "StandardGaussian"];
Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"], 
 SmoothHistogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", PlotStyle -> Blue], 
 Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, -7, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

So how to get the regular `Histogram[data]` and the `SmoothHistogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"]` on the same plot, with the same kind of overlay we see above, but with their respective y-axes?

[image]

Comment: Adding a right y-axis with the default ticks and changing the ticks of the left y-axis to custom ticks, that represent the counts, would be the simplest way to achieve the desired output by just adding the proper options settings to your code.

Comment: @Karsten7. Except that doesn't handle ensuring that the PDF is shown at the same scale as the counts...

Comment: @Karsten7. no? Counts are integers... PDF does not have to be, above I show the PDF option for Histogram, counts are much higher... Also, nope I do not recall posting this before.

Answer (score 2):

You may create [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) on one axis by scaling a height to its corresponding PDF scale.  I recommend specifying the [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) bin width so that you know the parameters for the scaling. Also all three are plotting `"PDF"`

Below I use bin widths of 0.5 so I know what value to include in the scaling function.

```
SeedRandom[54321];
data = RandomVariate[GumbelDistribution[], 1000];

Show[
 Histogram[data, {1/2}, "PDF"],
 SmoothHistogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", PlotStyle -> Blue], 
 Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, -7, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRangeClipping -> True,
 GridLines -> {None, Automatic},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {
   {
    {Sequence @@ #[[1]], Sequence @@ ({#, "", {.005, 0}} & /@ Flatten@#[[2]])} &@
       MapAt[{#, # 1000/2} &, {1, All}]@FindDivisions[{0, .5}, {5, 5}],
    {Sequence @@ N@#[[1]], Sequence @@ ({#, "", {.005, 0}} & /@ Flatten@#[[2]])} &@
       FindDivisions[{0, .5}, {5, 5}]
    },
   {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: that gets most of the way there, but the goal is to call `Histogram[data]` without the `PDF` specification. I am not quite sure what is going on with the `FrameTicks` but I think it is artificially making the left `FrameTicks` sequence?

Comment: @SumNeuron The y-axis ticks are directly calculated on both sides. The chart is on the `"PDF"` scale and automatically places ticks on the left on that scale. Therefore, I override those ticks with scaled count ticks and then add the pdf ticks to the right side. You can make a function that takes the data and calculates the ticks for you based on it..  That way the calculation will not be hardcoded to a particular solution.

Comment: that was the crux of the question... because using `Show` with the two different scales will not work.